# How to make word wrapping with inline-block

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm on some unordered lists which will always contain a quite long filename like this :

```
<ul>
<li>2018_0036_iso_mini_preview_208_Canon_flowers_light_garden_at_restaurant_toscana.jpg</li>
<li>480 X 300</li>
<li>Original</li>
</ul>
```

I need to make it responsive.

For this, I use the property break-word, which [handle the long file name.](https://jsfiddle.net/kcp0hypu/)

```
li {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

But I also need to display all the `li` items on a single line if there is enough space. 
For this I use

```
li {display:inline-block;}
```

But then the break-word proprerty [does not apply anymore](https://jsfiddle.net/xx6aosqj/).

How could I do to make word wrapping and inline-block applying in the same time ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as soon as you define it as `inline-block` the `<li>`-element doesn't have any forced `max-width`.

Setting `max-width` on your `<li>`-element should solve this issue:

```
li {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```